# Вывод категорий в поисковике Google под сайтом

Tags: seo

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такие категории под сайтом. И как они называются?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это называется "Ссылки сайта" https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=ru . Формируются автоматически, но в общем виде нужна понятная структура сайта, не помешают настроенные хлебные крошки, микроразметка, внутренняя перелинковка и, скорее всего, определенный порог посещаемости, т.е. даже с идеальной архитектурой блог Васи Пупкина с 5-ю посетителями в месяц такого сниппета не получит.

Ну и учитите, что эти сниппеты, как и все остальные, - запросозависимые, т.е. в зависимости от запроса расширенный сниппет может показываться, а может и нет.

http://i.prntscr.com/2hCFJPSlQw_bpvfCd-r_Lg.png

http://i.prntscr.com/j5nTU-RBQiupG5w0eRsNlg.png

http://i.prntscr.com/6zf0rs9iTyuubL4F_i980Q.png

Comment: Благодарю за пояснение